# Make Fn Key Control Numlock

Tags: fn-key, numlock

I have a VAIO laptop which, like most laptops, has an Fn key. In order for me to switch from the regular keyboard to the numeric keypad on the laptop, I am required to use NumLock; simply pressing the Fn key and then the number keys does not do anything.

Is there any way to make it so that I can just hold the Fn key to type numbers, instead of turning on NumLock?

Comment: Laptop Fn keys are not typically available to the operating system. You should be able to leave NumLock on then use Fn-J, for example, for "1" without it interfering with other keyboard functionality.

Comment: @Dennis: But if I leave it on, then I can't type letters without holding Fn... not all laptops behave the same way with NumLock. :(

Answer (score 2):

You didn't tell us what OS, but if it's Windows, you can use [KeyTweak](http://webpages.charter.net/krumsick/).

If it's Linux, you'll probably want to use [xmodmap](http://www.xfree86.org/4.2.0/xmodmap.1.html) in the X windows system.

I'm not sure how to do this in Mac OS X, but it is most probably similar to the Linux approach.

Comment: Yeah, it's Windows, sorry I forgot to write it. I took a look at keytweak, but I'm not sure how it helps -- would you please elaborate on it a bit?

Answer (score 0):

Enable Numlock using the Windows onscreen keyboard (osk.exe) instead of the physical keyboard and then use Fn to enter the numbers.